# Mongodb seeding in nextjs 14

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, next.js, mongodb-schema

I want to seed my static data to mongodb database using mongoose in my nextjs 14 project .
I am using typescript for this project.
I am saving two fields to the databse one for Users and second for Products.
But when I try to do it my Users data is shown in the database but my products data is not getting uploaded .
Need your help..

**DbConnect.ts**

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

async function dbConnect() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI!);
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Connection failed");
  }
}

export default dbConnect;
```

**route.ts**

```
import dbConnect from '@/lib/dbConnect'
import ProductModel from '@/lib/models/ProductModel'
import UserModel from '@/lib/models/UserModel'
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export const GET = async (request: NextRequest) =\> {

const { users, products } = data
await dbConnect()

await UserModel.deleteMany()
await UserModel.insertMany(users)

await ProductModel.deleteMany()
await ProductModel.insertMany(products)

return NextResponse.json({
message: 'seeded successfully',
users,
products,
})
}
```

My mongodb compass database shows this:
[products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/643p9.png)
[users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoiDB.png)

I dont know the error I am facing ... your help will be appreciated .
Thanks in advance.

I am trying to solve the mongodb data seeding procedure in nextjs 14 using mongoose.
Seeding the users and products data in the database , the users data is stored in the database but my products data does'nt got uploaded on the databsase.